# Background Cover with Fixed

Tags: html, css, background, fixed, cover

I'm trying to create a responsive, FIXED background that works on all major browsers.

Basically I'm after the typical background:cover behavior (scales with browser size) BUT, want the background to be fixed to create a parallax effect.

Is this even possible if so, how?

The CSS so far WITHOUT Fixed:

```
#front_header {
background: url(1.png) no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

#front_header .featured {
width: 100%;
max-width: 950px;
min-width: 755px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#front_header .txt {
margin: 19.5% 0 19.5%;
text-align:center;
display: block;
}
```

The Body HTML:

```
<section id="front_header">
<div class="featured">
<div class="txt">
<h2>Test</h2>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

As you can see, when you resize this, the background resizes slightly. However if I add

```
background-attached:fixed;
```

The background no longer resizes, only behaves like a fixed background should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

keep the

```
background-attached:fixed;
```

and instead of background-size: cover, try :

```
background-size: contain;
```

Also for future reference, try and add your code to : http://jsfiddle.net

it's best when you simulate the problem for everyone to see and help.